# What are the applications of copy and mutableCopy in actual projects?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What are the applications of copy and mutableCopy in actual projects?

```
NSString *str1 = @"test";
[str1 copy];

NSMutableString *mStr1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"test002"];
[mStr1 mutableCopy];

NSArray *arry1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2",nil];
[arry1 copy];

NSMutableArray *marry1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"value1", 
@"value2",nil];
[marry1 mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I know the different for them, but I want to know how to use them in the actual projects.

Comment: What do you mean about using them in the actual projects. That link provides all of their effect and how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *arry1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2",nil];
NSArray * testCopyArray =  [arry1 copy];  // returns immutable copy of array
NSMutableArray * testMutableCopyArray = [arry1 mutableCopy]; //// returns mutable copy of array
[testMutableCopyArray addObject:@"value3"]; // you can modify its values
```

If you are facing  use cases like you want to modify a `NSArray` value , you can assign its mutable copy to a `NSMutableArray` and modify it.

Comment: yep! so mutableCopy can use to exchange immutable to mutable object.

Comment: And how do you mutable exchange to immutable object?